# Customize my gallery in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I customize my gallery in wordpress and I found problem . How can i change my font on image thumbnails to color white ?

This is my site , problem is main gallery :

http://www.elefantti.iq.pl

Thanks for answers and your feedback.

Best Regards
Midget

Comment: You mean the color of text inside your images or? The <h3> one? "PUB4" ? My firefox browser shows the words as white, even when i check source it shows them as white?..

Comment: I mean <h3> Pub4</h3>  . I make lite tint on image , and tint also catch h3 . Is possible do this by css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h3>` elements are already colored white, but their `z-index` is too low. Add `z-index: 2;` to `.foogallery-album-gallery-list .foogallery-pile h3` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

For fix it you must only search or add in CSS the selector `.foogallery-album-gallery-list .foogallery-pile h3` and in the property:

```
.foogallery-album-gallery-list .foogallery-pile h3 {
background: transparent !important;
color: #fff !important;
z-index: 10;
}
```